# log4J causes error: The method getRootLogger() is undefined for the type Logger

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, log4j2

I created a sample dynamic web project to test log4j. The code highlighed with bold shows error and says :

> **'Error: The method getRootLogger() is undefined for the type Logger'**

The servlet snippet is as follows:

```
    private Logger logger = null;        

    logger = Logger.getLogger();

    BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

How to resolve this error.

Comment: Your error says "getRootLogger()" but your code says "getLogger()"  Did you paste the correct code and wrong error message?

Comment: I tried replacing getRootLogger() with getLogger(). That is a mistake while entering the question. However both displays the method to be undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is tagged Log4j2, here is how to get the root logger in Log4j2: `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger()`.

Comment: This resolves the issue with getRootLogger() error. But setLevel() shows error: undefined method. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: This question was just asked on the log4j-user mailing list. Here is a link to the reply: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201407.mbox/%3C3299CE04-6CFF-475C-BDAD-6F2E7440ADF4%40dslextreme.com%3E

Comment: Great. Now, that meant something

Answer (score 1):

try this if you're trying to implement logging using log4j logger:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Class Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to `getLogger()`

Use like this.

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyClass");  
logger.info("Started!..");
```

Comment: Sorry the same error appears with Logger.getLogger. logger.setLevel(FATAL) also shows error.

Comment: You don't need to use BasicConfigurator.configure(); and all. Just Initialize the logger. Then you will be able use it. See my latest answer.

Comment: But this 'undefined method' thing still persists. Which means Logger class does'not contain the aforesaid methods, is'nt it?

Comment: Ensure you imported this import org.apache.log4j.Logger; and added the  log4j.jar as library.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`import` Logger class from `org.apache.log4j.Logger`   package rather than other packages.

I hope this will work for you.